# Hold Hover event

Tags: jquery, html, css

I;m using this [hover-css-items](http://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/hover-css-tutorial-introduction/) to animate menu.

Particularly : **Background Transitions > Swipe to right.**

[image]

I need to hold the animation like in pic 2 while i leave the button (By default it will come to image 1 if i hover out).

***Initially the link is red... and on hover it animates to green ... and on hover out it comes back to red. 
I need to keep the link to green even if i hover out ... and externally trigger to go back to red.. when required by changing class.***

```css
.hvr-sweep-to-right {
  -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
  transform: translateZ(0);
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition-property: color;
  transition-property: color;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background: green;
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(0);
  transform: scaleX(0);
  -webkit-transform-origin: 0 50%;
  transform-origin: 0 50%;
  -webkit-transition-property: transform;
  transition-property: transform;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.3s;
  transition-duration: 0.3s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-out;
  transition-timing-function: ease-out;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:hover, .hvr-sweep-to-right:focus, .hvr-sweep-to-right:active {
  color: white;
}
.hvr-sweep-to-right:hover:before, .hvr-sweep-to-right:focus:before, .hvr-sweep-to-right:active:before {
  -webkit-transform: scaleX(1);
  transform: scaleX(1);
}

.try{
 height:80px;
 width:200px;
 background:red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="try hvr-sweep-to-right"> Link 1</li>
  
  <li class="try hvr-sweep-to-right"> Link 2 </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the html as well ?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't understand what you are trying to do. And by the way, you should include your HTML also in question.

Comment: @DemeterDimitri  updated ..

Comment: are you allowed to use JS/jQuery? I doubt that this is possible only is css

Comment: Yes.. I can use Jquery ... @Roysh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you will get the idea:

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  padding: 11px 16px;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  background: #ff3232;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: linear-gradient(to left, red 50%, blue 50%);
  background-size: 200% 100%;
  background-position: right bottom;
  margin-left: 10px;
  transition: all 2s ease;
}
div:hover {
  background-position: top left;
}
```

```html
<div>Hover</div>
```

Comment: How to separate the the two..
1. Going from left to right from red to blue 
2. From blue to red...back to normal...

can we make two different classes for this ?

Comment: you can use same class for both effect i am just changing background position, so no need any classes to differentiate

Comment: Make two seperate classes..

1.  Animation from Red to blue .. 
2 . Coming back from Blue to red..

Comment: bro you have to stay as blue or again have to blue from red

Comment: $(this).removeClass('hovered'); adding this on hoverout .. Solved the problem of coming back to red.. Thanks (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by adding class on hover state by using Jquery. Also some styling is required.

.hoverstate{background:red;}

```
$(".hvr-sweep-to-right").on("mouseover", function() {
  $(".hvr-sweep-to-right").addClass('hoverstate');
});
```

Comment: This could be done.. But, then coming back transition animation will not get played... as its already completed on hover out... We are jst holding the background color to red externally.

Comment: I dont get it, you want button to remain on hover state even after you remove the cursor. You have to change something from that element otherwise how will it know ?

Comment: Thanks .. https://jsfiddle.net/mhrjnsa1/qhqq20zm/7/ this solved the issue.. 

Actually i need to hold to green for a while then coming back to red with same animation ... whenever i need.. 

This will actually open a submenu .. so i need to hold to green while submenu is open .. and come back to red with transition when submenu is closed... 

So i need to separate the logic.

Comment: Ofcourse, when the panel is closed, you can trigger the following line. `$('.normal').attr('class','normal');`

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery it will be easy

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( ".try" ).hover(
    function() {
    }, function() {
    $(this).css({'background':'green'});
    }
  );
});
```

See fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/atg5m6ym/5846/

Comment: This could be done.. But, then coming back transition animation will not get played... as its already completed on hover out... We are jst holding the background color to green externally.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to your html

style

```
 .green{
    background: green;
    color: white;
  }
```

HTML

```
   <li class="try hvr-sweep-to-right" onmouseout="changeClass(this)"> Link 1</li>

  <li class="try hvr-sweep-to-right" onmouseout="changeClass(this)"> Link 2 </li>
```

JS

```
   function changeClass(x){
    if(!x.classList.contains("green"))
      x.classList += " green";
  }
```